# jdb print caught exception message

Tags: java, jdb

I have exceptions thrown in my java code when an error occurs. I then run the code using jdb so when the exception occurs, I can see the state that the code is in and debug. For all exceptions that I throw, I put in a useful string message. However, when jdb catches the exception, it doesn't print this string along with it. How do I print this string?

I have googled and searched and read the documentation but I can't figure out how.

If I have the test class:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("How do I view this string through jdb?");
    }
}
```

And run it through jdb:

```
$ jdb Test
Initializing jdb ...
> run
run Test
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: 
Exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (uncaught)"thread=main", Test.main(), line=3 bci=9

main[1]
```

Comment: why not just use a modern ide?

Comment: I would, but it is always an issue to change the command line parameters in the IDEs I have used (NetBeans and Eclipse). It is just easier for my to alt-tab to a terminal and do it.

Comment: You can't use an IDE when you're debugging a live environment!

Answer (score -1):

Check out the JDB "catch" command, for example "catch IllegalArgumentException".  Per the JDB [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html), it will cause the debugger to break when the exception is thrown so that you can probe into the details.  [This](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp212/00-spring/tutorials/07/index.html) document on debugging does a nice job explaining some of the downsides to being dependant on "print" statements, and also references the JDB "catch" functionality.

Comment: The only problem is that I throw different exceptions depending on the error IllegalArgument, IllegalState, AssertionError etc. The code base is not exactly small, and I don't remember all the exceptions I throw